# Calling a REST Service over a specific number of time simulatneously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have searched about this over internet but I wanted to learn about possible ways of achieving my task. What I am trying to do is that in my C# application I call a REST Service to get some data. I have used Tasks to simultaneously call the function which is calling the service. Now the service doesn't allow me to call it more then 5 times within a second because it gets overburden. I want to call the service through my function exactly 5 times. No more and no less. How can I control the number of asynchronous calls? I know it might be theoretical based question which needs to be researched but I am just asking for the possibilities and directions.

Comment: Are you making the same REST call 5 times per second, or are you requesting different information each time? Do you care whether the calls all happen at once, or should the 5 calls be spaced evenly within each second?

Comment: Different data is retrieved each time but the data that is passed can be same or different. All 5 requests should takes place in 1 second not 5 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from an algorithmic point of view ...

imagine a bucket that can hold x tokens ... every timeframe y you fill up the buckets so it holds x tokens. now you can have a number of workers that handle your requests to the service ... before a worker may access the service, it has to get a token from the bucket... only one worker may access the bucket at a given time, and a worker without a token waits in line until it can get one ... if your bucket still contains tokens, when you refill it, you have too few workers ... if you have more than z% of your workers waiting when you refill the bucket, you can get rid of some ...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You algorithm seems nice and logical. Could you guide me a little further incase of C#. Should I use thread or Parallel tasks? and how to keep the call limited to 5 times in a second. Thanks

Comment: task versus thread ... depends on your needs: if you create your own "thread pool" you have precise control about how it is done and how it will behave ... parallel task library will provide you with a ready to use implementation, but it's not optimized for your specific needs which means you will have to work around some issues

Comment: if you are asking what i would do ... i'd try to use TPL ... depending on what you want to send to the service (do you provide different requests, or is it allways "give me data!"?) you should set up a queue where you create and return Task<T> objects or your own interface to those (the point where you hand over the request and get a placeholder for the response; an interface here would allow you to replace Task<T> with something else later) ... from there you will need a timer for your interval ... fire x tasks up every time the interval is elapsed